# Displaying PowerBI and Microsoft Excel Files for Data Analytics Portfolio

Tags: data-analysis, excel, powerbi

I tried uploading a PowerBI file and an Excel file to GitHub, but it doesn't render them as GitHub would a Jupyter Notebook, for example.

What service can I upload the aforementioned files to for a data analytics portfolio, so potential employers can see my working without downloading anything?

Thank you.